# How do you prove that the limit of slopes of secant lines is indeed the slope of the tangent line?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, geometry

So, while reviewing the definitions of the derivative, I began to think of how we came up with the definition and why it makes sense. And I have been wondering about this for some time and the question is basically :How do you prove that the limit of Newton's difference quotient is equal to the slope of the tangent line. It makes sense intuitively but how does one rigorously prove it ?

Comment: How do you define tangent line?

Comment: Concerning the title, that's the wrong question. We're not taking limits of lines, we're taking limits of *slopes* of lines. Also, the difference quotient is equal to the slope of the secant line, not the slope of the tangent line; it is the *limit* of the difference quotient that yields the slope of the tangent line. If you are really interested in rigorous proofs, you have to start with precise and accurate statements!

Comment: @GerryMyerson I thought it would it was implied that if you say limit of lines it would mean limit of slopes of lines given the context, but I suppose I was mistaken. Regarding the other mistakes , I was a bit sloppy on those and so thank you for pointing them out.

Comment: So now the title equates a limit of slopes to a line – that's not an improvement!

Comment: Okay, I have fixed that as well. My apologies for not fixing that in the first edit.

Comment: Good. Now, you can answer the question of @velut – what is your definition of tangent line?

Comment: Today would be good, John.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to define the notion of "tangent line" first. I propose the following geometric condition: Given a curve
$$\gamma:\quad t\mapsto {\bf z}(t)\in{\mathbb R}^2\qquad (-h<t<h), \qquad \gamma(0)={\bf 0},$$
a line $\ell$ through ${\bf 0}$ is called *tangent* to $\gamma$ at ${\bf 0}$ if for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $\gamma\cap B_\delta({\bf 0})$ is contained in the double wedge with axis $\ell$ and angle width $\epsilon$.

Apply this definition to the situation where $\gamma$ is the graph of a differentiable function $f$ with $f(0)=0$, and use that $\tan$, resp., $\arctan$ are continuous.